# How to create Content Types with Drush

Tags: nodes, drush

Is it possible to create content types with Drush? Such as a new Galery content type?

I created a content type manually via web interface and checked the changes in database. However, there are quite a lot of changes - some changes are also in blob fields.

How do you do this?

Comment: why do you want to create contents types from drush?

Comment: i dont think there's a direct command, you could probably do `drush ev "node_type_save(array('type' => 'my type', 'name' => 'my type name'));"` check https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_set_defaults/7 for details

Comment: @saadlulu: For example I would want to create content types and fields with drush for fast prototyping a website.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to re-create content-types you have created in other drupal-installations you can use the [features](https://drupal.org/project/features) module:

This module allows you to export content-types to code (called features). Those features can be copied to other sites like normal modules and then be activated via drush using

drush en -y feature_name

Answer (score 1):

In the drush docs I don't see anything like `drush entitytype-bundle-create node foo` but I do see `drush field-create` which is pretty cool.

http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-7x/field/field-create